# How to change datatype from String Logstash to ISODate MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, logstash

I have some logs that read by Filebeat, filter in Logstash and sent to MongoDB. Filebeat generate @timestamp field on logs, the log might look like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("622884e8ed814f1590000076"),
    "@timestamp" : "\"2022-03-09T10:43:46.000\"",
    "stream" : "stderr",
    "message" : "[2022-03-09T10:43:46.528612+00:00] testing.INFO: Message error [] []"
}
```

but the @timestamp field write as String not Date. I have to read the timestamp as ISODate on MongoDB. It might look like this

```
"@timestamp": ISODate("2022-03-10T01:43:46.000Z")
```

instead of

```
"@timestamp" : "\"2022-03-09T10:43:46.000\""
```

Any suggestion how to change the datatype from string into date?

**UPDATE**
Trying to using match on date filter.

```
date {
       match => [ "@timestamp", "MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss",  "MMM  d yyyy HH:mm:ss", "ISO8601" ]
  } 
}
```

on mongo the datatype still not change. I also tried to make another field with current date (logstash_processed_at) with this

```
ruby {
        code => "event.set('logstash_processed_at', Time.now());"
        }
```

And using the date match too, but on the mongo the datatype still string

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of changing the filter it solved by adding new field on output mongodb at logstash config. the field is **isodate => true**.

```
output {
  mongodb {
    ...
    isodate => true
  }
}
```

This field change the @timestamp field from string to ISODate() format when it sent to mongodb. If you are looking for **how changing the timestamp into ISODate() in mongodb**, @R2D2 has the answer up there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to convert the timestamps already in mongoDB:

```
db.collection.update({},
 [
  {
   $addFields: {
    "@timestamp": {
      $dateFromString: {
         dateString: {
           $substr: [
            "$@timestamp",
            1,
            23
           ]
         }
       }
     }
   }
  }
 ],
 {
   multi: true
 })
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tDSF4ZoVI2l)

But you need to fix the injestion and use the logstash [filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html) in order to convert the date in string to date in ISODate():

```
filter {   
  date {
       match => [ "logdate", "MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss",  "MMM  d yyyy HH:mm:ss", "ISO8601" ]
  } 
}
```

Also check [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-mongodb.html) the monggodb output plugin:

isodate
Value type is boolean
Default value is false
If true, store the @timestamp field in MongoDB as an ISODate type instead of an ISO8601 string.

Comment: Hi, thankyou for your suggestion. I tried to using your way but on mongo the datatype still the same. It still shows as string not ISODate()

Comment: Aah forgot to mention the update/aggregation solution require mongodb version >=4.2  , what is your version?

Comment: check this ticket here it is detailed how to update field from another field in different versions also the old fasion way via JS for very earlier versions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field

Comment: Im running on docker with docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.15

Comment: Maybe I'm not clear enough, I want to sent the logs from logstash to mongo but with ISODate() data type in mongo. Your query pretty works for documents inside the collection but instead of running the query to change whats inside collection, I want to sent the logs and mongo read the timestamp as ISODate() data type not string. Is it possible? I'm running mongo 4.2.17 ver.